# JSON get result null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm developing an app using HTML5 with jQuery, and I am using Sync Framework for the synchronization and it consumes a service in the cloud (Windows Azure).

The problem is when I send the Request frame to the service:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        Accept: 'application / json',
        url: serviceUri,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(" reponse :" + json);

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
```

The Request frame is:

> GET http://157.56.8.203/DefaultScopeSyncService.svc/defaultscope /DownloadChanges?id=7AE7C771-0A98-4A5D-A046-430DDB0A7917 HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 157.56.8.203
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
>   Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Referer: htp://localhost:49427/ListSample.htm
>   Origin: htp://localhost:49427

And the Reply is:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-Length: 1388
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
>   SyncServiceVersion: 1.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 11:55:25 GMT
>
> {"d":{"_*sync":{"moreChangesAvailable":false,"serverBlob":"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"},"results":[{"Id":"7ae7c771-0a98-4a5d-a046-430ddb0a7917","Name":"Santiago","Surname":"Dalto","BirthDate":"/Date(917913600000)/","Gender":"M","*_metadata":{"uri":"http://157.56.8.203/DefaultScopeSyncService.svc/Persons(Id=guid'7ae7c771-0a98-4a5d-a046-430ddb0a7917')","type":"DefaultScope.Persons"}}]}}

The "data" object in the script is always null, but the reply frame has the correct data.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Where is your json function? aka of what do you expect your response?

Comment: data object in the script? Can you clarify on that part.Is the response correct and you are not finding a proper method to extract the response?

Comment: why don't you use Fiddler or any such tool to capture formatted JSON request and response. It will be easy for others to understand

Comment: well, the accept parameter looks kind-of funky. try removing the whitespaces or the the parameter all-together. Supplying dataType should be sufficient for jQuery to know what to expect and accept and that it should parse the fetched document to json.

Answer (score 0):

You must write the call function with this code, the reponse data you can get with **json.d.results** if the response has more than one object if you will get single object than you reach them with **json.d[0]**.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    Accept: 'application / json',
    url: serviceUri,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (json) {
    if (json.d.results == undefined) 
    {
        // to do
    }
    else {  
       console.log(" response :" + json.d.results);
    }

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain requests doesn't allowing in ALL modern browsers and it is not good to use them. In any case if you would like to receive your data you need to user your server like proxy, so it will work like this:

1. You implement request from server (YOUR SERVER) to another server
2. You call request to YOUR server, not to another (cross domain server)

Other ways is hucking.
I.e. you can use this link (BUT I don't suggest it) http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/